# SheepIt! Rendering produces weird icosphere-esque object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, sheepit

Whenever I render my scene in Blender (cycles) normally, It produces the following result (What I want):
[image]
Whenever I render it using SheepIt! (It is me rendering it) It produces the following:
[image]

I have no clue what that thing is. The two files are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem. SheepIt! Does not support fluid, which is why it made that shape.

Comment: I think sheep it does support fluid... You just have to bake all the files into the blend.

Comment: @10Replies It does, but the total .BLEND has to be 500mb or less, which you cant fit any fluid into that doesnt look low-poly.